# Повторное нажатие button

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp, raspberry-pi

Суть проблемы:
создаю приложение в UWP, которое загружаю в Windows IoT на raspberry.
Суть программы в включении/отключении реле на плате, которая связяна с raspberry по i2c.
Сама программа отрабатывает правильно, нажимаю кнопку - реле включается, нажимаю еще раз - выключается, но при повторном нажатии на включение - ничего не происходит. Подскажите, что может быть не так?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
using Windows.Devices.I2c;

// Документацию по шаблону элемента "Пустая страница" см. по адресу https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=402352&clcid=0x419

namespace App3
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Пустая страница, которую можно использовать саму по себе или для перехода внутри фрейма.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        I2cDevice I2C_PIC24FJ128GB106;
        DispatcherTimer timer;
        int addrSlave = 0x15;
        bool Pump = false;


        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitI2C();
        }

        async void InitI2C()
        {
            I2cConnectionSettings i2CConnectionSettings = new I2cConnectionSettings(addrSlave);
            i2CConnectionSettings.BusSpeed = I2cBusSpeed.StandardMode;
            I2cController i2CController = await I2cController.GetDefaultAsync();
            I2C_PIC24FJ128GB106 = i2CController.GetDevice(i2CConnectionSettings);
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var per1 = new byte[] { 13, 0x0 };
            var per2 = new byte[] { 13, 0x1 };

            if (Pump != false)
            {
                I2C_PIC24FJ128GB106.Write(per1);
            }
            else
            {
                Pump = true;
                I2C_PIC24FJ128GB106.Write(per2);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Аналогичная обработка метода на Python, где кнопка отрабатывает как нужно

```
def onButtonEnableLevel1(self):
        if self.enableLevel1 != False:            
            self.m_buttonEnableLevel1.configure(background=self.orig_color)           
            bus.write_byte_data(0x15, 13, 0x0)            
            self.enableLevel1 = False

        else:            
            self.enableLevel1 = True            
            self.m_buttonEnableLevel1.configure(background='#0078D7')            
            bus.write_byte_data(0x15, 13, 0x1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (Pump != false)
{
    Pump = false;
    I2C_PIC24FJ128GB106.Write(per1);
}
else
{
    Pump = true;
    I2C_PIC24FJ128GB106.Write(per2);
}
```

Постоянно подавали сигнал на выключение, поскольку флаг не вернули в соответствующее состоянию положение.

А вообще лучше сделать как-нибудь так:

```
public void DeviceSwitch()
{
     I2C_PIC24FJ128GB106.Write(Pump ?  per1: per2);
     Pump =!Pump;
}
```

И в `Button_Click` дергайте уже этот метод. Вообще в обработчике событий контролов логики быть не должно.

Плюс это

```
  var per1 = new byte[] { 13, 0x0 };
  var per2 = new byte[] { 13, 0x1 };
```

Вынесите в константы класса. И название переменным давайте более удобоваримые - еще спасибо за совет скажете, когда-нибудь. А еще лучше вообще из класса `MainPage` - всё это вынести в отдельный класс.